# Creating a navigation bar where each link has a different hover colour

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make a black navigation bar for my website, and when you hover over the first link it goes orange, the second link it goes green, etc. I know how to change colour on hover but don't know how to make each link different.

I figure its something to do with giving ids to each li tag?

```
<div id="navbar"> 
<ul> 
    <li id="link1"><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
    <li id="link2"><a href="2.html">2</a></li>
    <li id="link3"><a href="3.html">3</a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

But then how do I create different styles for each of these ids in the css file?
Below is what I tried

```
#navbar ul li a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #000000; 
}


#navbar ul li #link1 a:hover { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #C62222; 
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}

#navbar ul li #link2 a:hover { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #28C622; 
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're doing is on the right track, but don't repeat the CSS over and over:

```
#navbar ul li a:hover { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}

#navbar ul #link1 a:hover { 
    background-color: #C62222; 
}

#navbar ul #link2 a:hover { 
    background-color: #28C622; 
}
```

As others have noted, you also need to either remove the space between the `li` and your id, or just remove the `li` entirely (since there is only one `link1`, you don't necessarily need to tell the browser that it is an `li`).

Additionally, if you want, you can (and probably should) simply those selectors all the way down to `#link1 a:hover` and `#link2 a:hover`. It's more of a stylistic choice, but it helps to keep your code clean.

Comment: You should simplify those selectors while you're at it, and point out the error in his; that would make a great selected answer.

Comment: Thanks Mathletics, I added some more thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

You have a bad selector. The `li` is superfluous.

```
#navbar #link1 a:hover { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #C62222; 
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the space between `li` and `#link1`:

```
#navbar ul li#link1 a:hover
```

You could further optimize your CSS like this:

```
#navbar a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 25px 30px; /* shortcode for top/bottom - left/right */
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #000000; 
}
#navbar a:hover {  /* common hover styles */
    color: #ffffff; 
    padding:15px 30px;
}

#link1 a:hover { /* individual hover styles */
    background-color: #C62222; 
}

#link2 a:hover {  /* individual hover styles */
    background-color: #28C622; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the space between `li` and `#link2`.

```
#navbar ul li#link1 a:hover { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #C62222; 
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}

#navbar ul li#link2 a:hover { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #28C622; 
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but the space between `li` and `#linkX` is causing problems. These are not two separate elements, so they should be combined. One possible method is:

```
#navbar ul li#link1 a:hover {
    ....
```

Alternately, you can use:

```
#navbar ul #link1 a:hover {
    ....
```

You may wish to combine the duplicated styles into a single directive:

```
#navbar ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff; 
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

Then use only the changed style as needed:

```
#link1 a:hover {
    background-color: #C62222;
}
```