# CSS Menu Multiple Hover Colo(u)rs

Tags: css, menu

Apologies for what is probably quite a basic question, but I've not found a solution to this online.

I have a simple CSS menu, here's the CSS:

```css
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    opacity:1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li {
    float: left; 
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* End navigation bar styling. */
```

This is from an online tutorial, so not my code.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

All I want to do is have different colo(u)rs for each menu item when hovered over.
I assume you need to create a separate id (or class) for each item, but I am unsure of the syntax and no matter what I try it simply won't work.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: do you want the text color to change or the background color?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716686/creating-a-navigation-bar-where-each-link-has-a-different-hover-colour

Comment: It's the background colour thanks.

Comment: all the answers below work, so i'm not going to write a new one. But Chad's answer brings up the point that nth-child can be a pain to modify later on. Your options are separate classes for each item or the nth-child. I'd choose separate classes

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:nth-child` selector but it [won't work](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3anth-child) in some legacy versions of IE.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PuW3s/)

```css
#nav li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
 color:green;
}

#nav li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
color:blue; 
}
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, as long as it's fine with IE8 and up I'm OK with that, the Luddites need to upgrade ;) Is that what you mean by "legacy"?

Answer (score 2):

add a class to the href links and then in your css call the hover state and then style accordingly.  Here is an example using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/LGL37/

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="about">TEXT</a>
```

The CSS

```
.about:hover { background: yellow; }
```

EDIT: this is a much better solution than the other answer as it is cross browser compatible and if you need to style more in the future you'll have individual classes to target rather than nth which can get confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the `:nth-child()` selector, you can add a unique class to each `li` in the `nav`

```
<li class="about"><a href="#"></a></li>
```

and set a hover effect in your stylesheet for that specific class

```
#nav li.about a:hover { background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use nth-child:

```
li:nth-child(2) a:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fAbFg/

This example affects the second item.