# Creating Navbar where each link has a different color when hover

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, navbar

Trying to change individual links in navbar to different colors when hovered. Can't seem to figure it out.

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

<!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#HOME"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#link1">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#link2">2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#link3">3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#link4">4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-custom li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active 
{
outline: 0;
background-color: #bdc3c7 !important;
color: #fff;
}
```

Have the current links set to red. But would like each individual link to have a different color. E.g. Link1 = Red, Link2 = Blue.

I am having trouble doing this! Help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716686/creating-a-navigation-bar-where-each-link-has-a-different-hover-colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use **SASS**, it could be done in a more cleaner way like this in your scss file:

```
$colors: (1: red, 2: blue, 3: yellow, 4: black);

@each $anchor, $color in $colors {
   #{".navbar-custom .nav li:nth-child("+ (1 + $anchor) + ") a:hover"} {
       background-color: $color;
    }
}
```

which will **generate the CSS**:

```
.navbar-custom .nav li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li:nth-child(4) a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Now you could add as many as different colors for all your links and let the SASS generate the CSS for you.

Comment: awesome. just added to my scss and adjusted the color and BOOM. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, just need to `class` them up uniquely

**HTML**

```
        <li class="hidden colour1">
            <a href="#HOME"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-scroll colour2">
            <a href="#link1">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-scroll colour3">
            <a href="#link2">2</a>
        </li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.colour1:hover { background-color:blue; }
.colour2:hover { background-color:red; }
.colour3:hover { background-color:green; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to assign their CSS for each individual class and give the different link different class

like

```
.pagescroll1{

}
.pagescroll2{

}
```

and the call them from your HTML

Answer (score 0):

The elegant solution is to select by attribute value. example for the first one:

```
a[href="#link1"]:hover,
a[href="#link1"]:active,
{
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #bdc3c7 !important;
  color: #fff;
}
```

however, this works only when you're directly selecting the a-elements. With your third selector li.active, there is no information in that element as to where it links. in this case, you'll have to add classes as suggested by rob.